# Prepared MYSQL statement not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have been struggling with this for very long now so I would apprechiate it if someone could point out if there's anything directly wrong with my statement?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cases 
                            (identifier, title, description, action)    
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $identifier, $title, $description, $action);
$stmt->execute();

$identifier = "a";
$title = "a";
$description = "a";
$action = "a";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Nothing is inserted into my table.

Comment: Why are you defining the variable after executing the query ?

Comment: Any errors? What's the value of `$identifier` before preparing the statement?

Comment: if you switch on error reporting it will likely tell you quite clearly what is going wrong. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @ADyson, not mysqli...

Comment: You execute the query `->execute()` BEFORE setting the values of your bound parameters !!! _If I send you to the shop to buy a programmer but I dont give you any money, how many programmers will you return with_

Comment: When something doesn't work as expected, the first place to look at is error logs. Set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to exception and execute the block in try catch. Also check mysql error logs.

Comment: @marekful what would you say it is then? PDO doesn't have a [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method (it has `bindParam()` instead. The name and the values it accepts are somewhat different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is inserted as you're defining your variables AFTER you've executed the statement. So it's not going to enter anything. It's like trying to write something on a postcard after you've put it in the postbox.

```
$identifier = "a";
$title = "a";
$description = "a";
$action = "a";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cases (identifier, title, description, action) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $identifier, $title, $description, $action);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now, I haven't seen your `$conn` variable so, provided that's okay. This should fix your issue.

Comment: :) :) _It's like trying to write something on a postcard after you've put it in the postbox_ :) :)

Comment: Particularly proud of that one.. thanks Riggs! glad I made your Christmas! :D

Comment: Oh you did that my friend, much better than my analogy :)